# PYTHONPATH=$(shell pwd) leads to 'PYTHONPATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, gnu-make

Quick Edit: This project was made with linux, and I am using windows 10.

I started working on a deep learning project forked from github. After adjusting and installing python, miniconda, venv, required packages, and adjusting paths in the project as requested by the author, it was time to train the model. The author uses a Makefile to train, extract features, etc.. The following command is used to train the model `make train`, and the full code of this train part in the Makefile is

```
CONFIG_PATH=./experiments/configs/
CONFIG_NAME=seld.yml
OUTPUT=./outputs   # Directory to save output
EXP_SUFFIX=_test   # the experiment name = CONFIG_NAME + EXP_SUFFIX
RESUME=False
GPU_NUM=0  # Set to -1 if there is no GPU

.phony: train
train:
    PYTHONPATH=$(shell cd) CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="${GPU_NUM}" python experiments/train.py --exp_config="${CONFIG_PATH}${CONFIG_NAME}" --exp_group_dir=$(OUTPUT) --exp_suffix=$(EXP_SUFFIX) --resume=$(RESUME)
```

PS: the last line is line 38

When I use `make train`, the following error happens:

```
> make train
PYTHONPATH=D:\GUC\Semester 8 (Bachelor)\SALSA CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0  " python experiments/train.py --exp_config="./experiments/configs/seld.yml" --exp_group_dir=./outputs    --exp_suffix=_test    --resume=False
'PYTHONPATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:38: train] Error 1
```

After editing and changing a lot in the system environmental variables, this is currently my path and pythonpath in both the user and system variables.

PS:

1. "salsa" is the name of the conda env.
2. I added a lot of paths hoping for it to work, but it didn't.
3. In the third path of the first image, that miniconda was the one that did it, there is no "usr" folder inside Library.

[Image 1 - path in user variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd2I0.png)

[Image 2 - pythonpath in user variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct9GY.png)

[Image 3 - path in system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdnVf.png)

[Image 4 - pythonpath in system variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ao3u.png)

Right now, I found no fix whatsoever online that worked for me. Since the problem states that "PYTHONPATH is not recognized", I applied every fix available online for editing the system env variables, but still not fixed.

Also, for some reason, the `$(shell pwd)` does return the path, but if I write `pwd` in the terminal, it works fine.

I tried using the miniconda terminal, vscode, and pycharm, but all yeld to the same error. I even adjusted vscode's settings to make the default python interpreter the python.exe that is in my env in miniconda. But still...

Comment: `key1=value1 key2=value2 command arg1 arg2 ...` is UNIX command-line syntax to temporarily set an environment variable for the duration of a single command. Your error means your makefile is running a non-UNIX shell -- specifically, it looks like Windows `cmd.exe` -- that doesn't recognize or honor that syntax.

Comment: Nothing about this problem is specific to Python in any way. You'd have the same issue trying to set _any_ environment variable for the duration of _any_ command from a makefile on this system. Tagging "makefile" because we don't know which version of `make` you have; if you figure that out, please amend the tagging to make it more specific. (If it's GNU make, `make --version` will tell you which version).

Comment: ...you _may_ be able to set the `SHELL` variable in your makefile to point to a more POSIX-y shell, but exactly what that looks like depends on details you haven't given us (which version of `make` you have, which compatibility layer if any it's using to run on Windows, etc).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is GNU Make 4.2.1, and yes indeed, the author was using ubuntu for this project. But due to my lack of knowledge in linux and deep learning in gerneral, I thought that ubuntu is only a standalone linux os, and I don't have to install it. But now, I can see that I download and use its terminal. Could this fix everything?

Comment: If what you're talking about (re: "download and use its terminal") is Microsoft's Linux compatibility layer, that gives you a real Ubuntu userland running on top of a Microsoft kernel. That real userland includes a POSIX-compliant shell, so yes, building this code inside it will fix your problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you know what is the equivelent of this line in windows?


PYTHONPATH=$(shell cd) CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="${GPU_NUM}" python experiments/train.py --exp_config="${CONFIG_PATH}${CONFIG_NAME}" --exp_group_dir=$(OUTPUT) --exp_suffix=$(EXP_SUFFIX) --resume=$(RESUME)

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is outside my expertise. I answer questions about how it works on a POSIX-y shell (though parts of it are for interpretation by `make` and not by a shell at all), but not how to duplicate it with cmd.exe/PowerShell/other Windows tools.